# Checking a column with two attributes

Tags: sql-server

I have list of names that have either one checking account and/or one saving account linked to their direct deposit. 22 means checking and 32 means savings.

If they have just a checking account (22) or just a savings account (32) in the column then I want to have a '100%' in the column next to it. However, if a person has a checking and a savings account, I want to leave it blank. (We have to manually look in another software for the information)

Example

`Employee #   Account      Allocated % 
 100          22

 100          32

 101          22              100
 102          32              100`

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET [Allocated %] = 100
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE t1.Account IN (22,32)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM YourTable t2
        WHERE t2.[Employee #] = t1.[Employee #]
            AND t2.Account IN (22,32)
            AND t2.Account <> t1.Account
    )
```

But you should, of course, sanity check it first:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourTable.Account IN (22,32)
    AND YourTable.[Employee #] IN (
        SELECT t1.[Employee #]
        FROM YourTable t1
        WHERE t1.Account IN (22,32)
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM YourTable t2
                WHERE t2.[Employee #] = t1.[Employee #]
                    AND t2.Account <> t1.Account
                    AND t2.Account IN (22,32)
            )
    )
ORDER BY [Employee #], Account;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can group by Employee #, and have a flag that checks for a 22 and a flag that checks for 32 using a case statement.

**Test Scenario**

```
select *
into ##tempAccounts
from (
select EmployeeNum = 100, Account = 22
union all select EmployeeNum = 100, Account = 32
union all select EmployeeNum = 101, Account = 22
union all select EmployeeNum = 102, Account = 32
) x


select *  from ##tempAccounts


select 
    Accounts.EmployeeNum, 
    Accounts.Account,
    case when AccountStatHelper.Has22 = 1 and AccountStatHelper.Has32 = 1 then Null else '100%' end
from ##tempAccounts as Accounts
left join
(
    select
        EmployeeNum,
        Has22 = max(case when Account = 22 then 1 else 0 end),
        Has32 = max(case when Account = 32 then 1 else 0 end)
    from ##tempAccounts
    group by EmployeeNum
) AccountStatHelper on Accounts.EmployeeNum = AccountStatHelper.EmployeeNum


drop table ##tempAccounts
```

**Result**

```
EmployeeNum Account     
----------- ----------- ----
100         22          NULL
100         32          NULL
101         22          100%
102         32          100%
```

Answer (score 0):

A real simple way to do this is like this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts WHERE EmpNo = A.EmpNo) = 1 
     THEN 100 ELSE NULL END AS Allocation FROM Accounts A
```

This does not check for `22` or `32` status. It's simply seeing if they have more then one type of account. This is probably the most straightforward way, assuming your logic is they have more than one account, then it needs to be 100.

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0fd21c/6).